# Understanding errors in printing a Linked list in C++

Tags: c++, g++

I have recently worked on C, but I have started to study C++. I had a homework in to create a program that would read texts and organize data out of the imputed text. This is the last part I have left, but I don't get what's wrong with my code. This part of the problem is pretty simple, but I still don't understand what my errors are. I got used to gcc compiler which wrote mostly segmentation fault, but g++ compiler errors are different. Any tips or hints on what to pay more attention while transferring from c to c++ would be really appreciated.

This is my output errors.

```
-bash-3.2$ g++ -o Printfunction Printfunction.cpp
Printfunction.cpp: In function 'void Printfunction(wordList*)':
Printfunction.cpp:43: error: cannot convert 'NumberList*' to 'Numberlist*' for argument '1' to 'std::string returnlist(Numberlist*)'
Printfunction.cpp: In function 'std::string returnlist(Numberlist*)':
Printfunction.cpp:56: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct Numberlist'
Printfunction.cpp:10: error: forward declaration of 'struct Numberlist'
Printfunction.cpp:56: error: 'to_string' was not declared in this scope
Printfunction.cpp:57: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct Numberlist'
Printfunction.cpp:10: error: forward declaration of 'struct Numberlist'
```

Can you please tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct NumberList
{
    int line;
    struct Numberlist *nextPtr;
};

struct wordList
{
    string word;
    int Count;
    NumberList lines;
    struct wordList *nextPtr;
};

void Printfunction(wordList *list);
string returnlist(Numberlist *list);

int main()
{
    wordList something;
    something.word = "SOMETHING";
    something.Count = 55555;
    something.nextPtr = NULL;
    Printfunction(&something);

}

void Printfunction(wordList *list)
{
    int i;
    i=1;
    cout<<"+----+----------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+"<<endl;
    cout<<"|#   |          WORD              | COUNT |             LINES               |"<<endl;
    cout<<"+----+----------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+"<<endl;
    while(list != NULL)
    {
        cout<<"|"<<left<<setw(4)<<i<<"|"<<left<<setw(28)<<list->word<<"|"<<left<<setw(7)<<list->Count<<"|"<<left<<setw(33)<<returnlist(&(list->lines))<<"|"<<endl;
        cout<<"+----+----------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+"<<endl;
        list = list->nextPtr;
        i++;
    }
}

string returnlist(Numberlist *list)
{
    string final;
    while(list != NULL)
    {
        final.append(", ");
        final.append(to_string(list->line));
        list = list->nextPtr;
    }
    final.append(".");
    return final;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that sometimes you spell it `NumberList`, and sometimes you spell it `Numberlist`.

> Any tips or hints on what to pay more attention

*Case matters.*

Comment: @vatomargvelashvili: Yes :)

Comment: I can't as it got answered :(

Comment: @vatomargvelashvili: teehee

Comment: I don't get why to_string doesn't work. As I searched the error I found that I should enable c++11 by "-std=c++11", but I don't get how and where I should put "-std=c++11";

Comment: @vatomargvelashvili: As an argument to your compiler invocation. Keep searching for how to use C++11; you'll find it.

Comment: As i get it it is a flag. so I used it while calling the file 
Like this: g++ -std=c++11 Printfunction.cpp -o main, but it tells me as unrecognised command line

Comment: @vatomargvelashvili: You're using it correctly. Your compiler version may be too old.